# Audio isn't playing in js

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I've been having this problem where audio wouldn't play. I am trying to get a random sound to play but nothing happens when I click on the image (which has an `onclick="playRandomSound()"`). This is my code.

```js
var sound1 = new Audio("InDeed.wav");
var sound2 = new Audio("Indeed2.wav");
var sound3 = new Audio("Yeeees.wav");
var sound4 = new Audio("girl_shut_up.wav");
var sound5 = new Audio("imhmmm.wav");
var randomizer;
function playRandomSound(){
    randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    if (randomizer === 0){
        sound1.play();
    } else if (randomizer == 1){
        sound2.play();
    } else if (randomizer == 2){
        sound3.play();
    } else if (randomizer == 3){
        sound4.play();
    } else if (randomizer == 4){
        sound5.play();
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
}
#rokas {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4lO3dpT.jpg" id="rokas" onclick="playRandomSound()">
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: It should work. Make sure that the files are in the same directory as the html file. And make sure that script and the audio files are loaded when you call `playRandomSound()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to update your code like this:

html:

```
<audio style="display: none;" id="sound"></audio>
```

js:

```
function playRandomSound () {
  var sound = document.getElementById('sound');
  randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);

  if (randomizer === 0){
    sound.src = sound1;
  } else if (randomizer == 1){
    sound.src = sound2;
  } else if (randomizer == 2){
    sound.src = sound3;
  } else if (randomizer == 3){
    sound.src = sound4;
  } else if (randomizer == 4){
    sound.src = sound5;
  }
  sound.load();
  sound.play();  
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the tag...

```
<audio id="audioPlaceHolder" src="InDeed.wav" autostart="false" ></audio>
```

You can dynamically change the src from your JavaScript.

For playing it...

```
var sound = document.getElementById('audioPlaceHolder');
sound.play();
```

enjoy!